# Creating folders and subfolders from Excel cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to create a directory named as the value in column `E` within a directory (`c:/Site Information`), then create a further directory called the concatenated value of column `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.  This value is created in column `H` in my sheet.

The directories created `C:/Site Information/value column E/Column H` would be the result.

Then I've been trying to create a hyperlink in column `B` to this folder and ensure this happens every time a new record is added to subsequent rows.

I'm new to VBS and wanted to know if this is possible.  Also if the directory "`value column E`" already exists I need the sub directory to be created in this existing directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is as far as my limited macro skills have allowed me to go.

```
Sub Create_Folders()

'Parent folder.
ParentFolder = "C:\Site Information"
'Create the folders from selected cells
Dim Rng As Range
Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer
Set Rng = Selection
maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count

For c = 1 To maxCols
    r = 1
    Do While r <= maxRows
        If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir (ParentFolder & "\" & Rng(r, c))

            On Error Resume Next
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Loop

Next c
End Sub
```

This creates folders in my parent folder. That's all so far.

I've now tried to simplify the task by moving the required fields to a new sheet and concatenating the required fields.

I then run the following VBA

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    For Each objRow In UsedRange.Rows
        strFolders = "C:\Site Information"
        For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
            strFolders = strFolders & "\" & objCell
            Shell ("cmd /c md " & Chr(34) & strFolders & Chr(34))
        Next
        Dim FSO As Object
        Dim FromPath As String
        Dim ToPath As String
        FromPath = "C:\Server Filing"  'predifined folders
        ToPath = strFolders     '<< created sub directory
        If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
            MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    Next
End Sub
```

When I run this it works down the sheet creating a directory named after column 1 and then a sub folder in that named after column 2.

I then try to copy a set of predefined folders into this folder.

Halts on 
**`FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath`**
with *path not found* yet when debugging the paths are present.

Need to get over this hurdle then try and automate the creation of the hyperlink.

Any ideas?

In case anyone is interested putting a pause in the loop allowed the cmd time to copy the folder solving the path not found issue.

```
Private Sub Createfolders_Click()
Sheets("Create Folders").Select
For Each objRow In UsedRange.Rows
    strFolders = "C:\Site Information"
    For Each objcell In objRow.Cells
        strFolders = strFolders & "\" & objcell
        Shell ("cmd /c md " & Chr(34) & strFolders & Chr(34))
    Next
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    FromPath = "C:\Server Filing"  '------ Folder were pre defined folders are
    ToPath = strFolders     '<< Change------ Created sub folder
    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ToPath = "C:\Site Information\\" Then
        MsgBox "Finished"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)
        FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Just want to generate a hyper link to each folder now.  This has me stumped.

Comment: Please include also hat have you tried up to now? You need to do some efforts yourself instead of asking for a complete solution. You can find several resources on the internet about creating folders by VBA.

Comment: I have not asked for a complete solution, I've outline what I'm trying to do and asked for help.

Comment: You should create a form for inserting new record instead of allowing the user to directory enter the values in the sheet. Then you can create the folders as you required and insert the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these links https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840672.aspx

I think this will help you.

Comment: You should flesh out your answer more instead of providing only links, since future readers might not be able to figure out what to do exactly.